# How to use unix find and exclude paths?

Tags: macos, unix

I need to exclude Time Machine path /Volumes/somedrive/Backups.backupdb from the results of `find`.

I currently use the following code, but it generates massive logs as it finds and includes all files in the Time Machine folder:

```
do shell script "find -x " & from_path & " -print0 | xargs -0 ls -d -F -P -l -T -a -e -i -o -p -q " & from_path & " > " & to_path user name "name" password "pass" with administrator privileges
```

I tried some examples from this site but I can't figure it out.

How I can use find and exclude certain paths?

Comment: The `-x` will exclude your Time Machine volume. Remove the `& from_path` after `xargs` in your `do shell script` statement.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great answer over on Stack Overflow covering this: [Exclude directory from find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4210072)

Essentially, the command to exclude directories from `find` is as follows:

```
find . -type d \( -path dir1 -o -path dir2 -o -path dir3 \) -prune -o -print
```

From the above example, you should be able to extrapolate excluding a single directory.

#### A brief explanation:

```
-type d        # type: directories
-path dir1     # your path
-o             # "or"
-prune         # skip the previous set
-print         # print results
```